# A TypeError because the list indices must be integers or slices, and not tuple

Tags: python, arrays, typeerror

I've tried my best to search for ways to fix a problem With arrays and tuples, but i couldn't find anything that helped me. This is the problem:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

I'm creating a text based game where i use arrays inside arrays to make a map:

```
maps = [
[
    #Room 1
    ['0','0','0','0','0'],
    ['0','x','.','x','0'],
    ['0','x','x','x','0'],
    ['0','.','x','.','0'],
    ['0','0','0','0','0']
]
[
    #Room 2
    ['0','0','0','0','0'],
    ['0','.','x','.','0'],
    ['0','x','x','x','0'],
    ['0','.','.','x','0'],
    ['0','0','0','0','0']
]
]
```

Unfortunately, the last array gives me the TypeError:
   TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
The code looks like this:

```
['0','0','0','0','0']
```

What have i done wrong?

Comment: You need a comma between your two lists

Comment: Please show, how you index your list. And you also missed a comma...

Comment: Oh, thanks Wondercricket!

Comment: @SimSon The comma is what's causing the error. Since there is no comma separating the two lists, Python is attempting to access the index of the first list with the second list

Answer (score 1):

You missed a comma between the two `sub-arrays` which led Python to misinterpret this as you `indexing` the first `array` with the second `array`.

I'm pretty sure this is what you meant to do:

```
maps = [
[
    #Room 1
    ['0','0','0','0','0'],
    ['0','x','.','x','0'],
    ['0','x','x','x','0'],
    ['0','.','x','.','0'],
    ['0','0','0','0','0']
],
[
    #Room 2
    ['0','0','0','0','0'],
    ['0','.','x','.','0'],
    ['0','x','x','x','0'],
    ['0','.','.','x','0'],
    ['0','0','0','0','0']
]
]
```

Also, you tagged the question with [`array`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/arrays/info), yet what you have defined here is a `list`. If you want a `numpy array`, you would define that like so:

```
maps = np.array([
[
    #Room 1
    ['0','0','0','0','0'],
    ['0','x','.','x','0'],
    ['0','x','x','x','0'],
    ['0','.','x','.','0'],
    ['0','0','0','0','0']
],
[
    #Room 2
    ['0','0','0','0','0'],
    ['0','.','x','.','0'],
    ['0','x','x','x','0'],
    ['0','.','.','x','0'],
    ['0','0','0','0','0']
]
])
```